# How to Use The CD4067BE Library for Multiple Buttons

Tags: c++, button, arduino, arduino-ide

I just have a small problem with this Arduino library: [CD74HC4067](https://github.com/waspinator/CD74HC4067). I am not sure how to use multiple buttons with this multiplexer library. I have an Arduino Mega 2560 and the CD4067BE [multiplexer]. The connections are fairly simple: just like this, but with the signal pins going to 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/278321/reducing-the-number-of-pins-needed-to-read-a-12-key-keypad-where-the-buttons-are.
[CD4067BE datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4067.pdf?ts=1621636026345&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).
Here is the code:

```
/*
   Controlling and looping through a CD74HC4067's channel outputs


   Connect the four control pins to any unused digital or analog pins.
   This example uses digital pins 4, 5, 6, and 7.

   Connect the common pin to any other available pin. This is the pin that will be
   shared between the 16 channels of the CD74HC4067. The 16 channels will inherit the
   capabilities of the common pin. For example, if it's connected to an analog pin,
   you will be able to use analogRead on each of the 16 channels.

*/

#include <CD74HC4067.h>

// s0 s1 s2 s3
CD74HC4067 my_mux(2, 3, 4, 5);  // create a new CD74HC4067 object with its four control pins

const byte g_common_pin = 6; // select a pin to share with the 16 channels of the CD74HC4067

const byte ledPin = 7;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(g_common_pin, INPUT_PULLUP); // set the initial mode of the common pin.
  // This can be changed in loop() for each channel.

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop()
{

  my_mux.channel(0);
 

  if (digitalRead(g_common_pin) == LOW) {

    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

  }

  else {

    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What doesn't work? What do you expecting it from? What you are getting now?

Comment: My question is: how do I get this library to work with multiple buttons using this multiplexer? The sample code above works with one button, but I don't know how to use multiple buttons with this library. I expect to use 12 buttons to work with this multiplexer and the library. I am getting a LED turn on when I press the button. So, the test code works, just, again, don't know how to make this work using twelve buttons.

Comment: 1) put your question as part of your post, not in comment. 2) Do you understand how the the multiplex and the library works? Working with 12 buttons is just the same as working with one, you select the button you want to read with `my_mux.channel(x)` and then you read the input to get the button x value.

Comment: 1) How do I put the question as part of my post? 2) No, I don't understand how the multiplex and the library works. Unless, it goes something like this: the mux is a chip that can act as a switch based on a "truth table"; the library can simplify this process by "scanning" through the mux's channels by adding simpler code. And I think I don't understand what you mean by the "selecting button" part. Maybe like "my_mux.channel(0)" and then "my_mux.channel(1);" I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to my problem: I needed to scan the individual channels to determine which one was being pressed. Here is the code, in case anyone is interested:

```
/*
   Controlling and looping through a CD74HC4067's channel outputs


   Connect the four control pins to any unused digital or analog pins.
   This example uses digital pins 4, 5, 6, and 7.

   Connect the common pin to any other available pin. This is the pin that will be
   shared between the 16 channels of the CD74HC4067. The 16 channels will inherit the
   capabilities of the common pin. For example, if it's connected to an analog pin,
   you will be able to use analogRead on each of the 16 channels.

*/

#include <CD74HC4067.h>

// s0 s1 s2 s3
CD74HC4067 my_mux(2, 3, 4, 5);  // create a new CD74HC4067 object with its four control pins

const byte g_common_pin = 6; // select a pin to share with the 16 channels of the CD74HC4067

const byte ledPin = 7;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(g_common_pin, INPUT_PULLUP); // set the initial mode of the common pin.
  // This can be changed in loop() for each channel.

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop()
{
  /*
    my_mux.channel(1);

    if (digitalRead(g_common_pin) == LOW) {

        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        function();

      }

      else {

        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

      }
  */

  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {

    Serial.println(i);

    my_mux.channel(i);



    if (digitalRead(g_common_pin) == LOW) {

      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      //function();

    }

    else {

      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);


    }

    delay(1000);

    /*
        }

        void function() {

        Serial.print("In function");

        }
    */
  }
}
```